# Python Pandas: Using corrwith and getting "outputs are collapsed"

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I want to find out how a column of data in a matrix correlates with the other columns in the matrix.
The data looks like;
[image]
I use the following code;

```
selected_product = "5002.0"
df_single_product = df_recommender[selected_product]
df_similar_to_selected_product=df_recommender.corrwith(df_single_product)
df_similar_to_selected_product.head()
```

The output from the head command is not produced. Instead I get a message saying "Outputs are collapsed". Why is this happening? is this a error I can trap or is the code wrong?
Maybe there are too many rows? I am using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer. The df_single_product variable which I thought would be a dataframe is in fact a series. To correct that I entered the following change to the code;

```
df_single_product = df_recommender[selected_product].to_frame()
```